# NSArray. How do I implement the Map function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, mapreduce

In iOS I want to implement the map function for NSArray. This is a function that is applied to every element of the array. What is the best way to implement this?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Map is a transform from one thing to another...you are looking for "foreach", not map...that said, the accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) function of `NSArray`.

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    // Body of the function
}];
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight yes sir we have a winner. That'll work quite nicely. Thanks for this. Cheers.

Comment: Why is this a winner. A map function should return a new array where each element of the original has been acted on by the block. enumerateObjectsUsingBlock returns void.

Comment: @SaniElfishawy What OP calls "map" differs from a more common definition: he wanted a "foreach" mechanism to apply his own function (the first part of the classic "map") but he did not want to collect the results of the transform (the second part of the "map" functionality). I answered the question based on OP's description of the desired functionality, i.e. "This is a function that is applied to every element of the array."

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for apply as map should return a new array with the transformed values.

However you can augment NSArray with the methods you look for by creating a custom category. Here are two examples - apply and map:

```
@implementation NSArray (CMMap)
- (NSArray *) map:(id(^)(id obj))block {
    NSMutableArray *a = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (id o in self) {
        id on = block(o);
        if (!on) {
            NSLog(@"NSArray::map() - object returned by block is nil!");
            abort();
        }
        [a addObject: on];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray: a];
}

- (void) apply:(void(^)(id obj))block {
    for (id o in self) {
        block(o);
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Objective-C, you can simply use these methods:

```
- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(nullable id)argument;
```

For example:

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doSomething)];
```